# Save text field value in drop down menu

Tags: html

I am creating a form in HTML and I wanted make a dropdown menu which acts as text field also. For example, if user inputs a new value in text field which is not present in drop down then new value should be saved(may be on-click on save button) in dropdown menu and next time that value should be available for selection.

**Or**

On-click of button, a separate textbox which will populate new values to existing dropdown menu is also sufficient.

I am currently trying with http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html
And initializing:

```
<input type="text" name="myText" value="Norway"
   selectBoxOptions="Canada;Denmark;Finland;Germany;Mexico">
```

But not sure how to proceed further to save new input to dropdown menu.

Is there HTML code to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to dip into Javascript to do anything dynamic like this.

Comment: If I understand correctly you'd need to create a database to store all the information. This requires a fair amount of code and isn't a simple question.